# The oldValue value in the property observer is always the same in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I have collectionView and there is a radioButton in my custom cell.I assigned cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row in cellforAt function of my collection view.Then, I created a property observer like as follows. I click different data but oldValue is printing with same value . (You can see in the photo I've clicked shooter and strategy ones.)

```
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0 {
    
    didSet {
        
        print("old \(oldValue), current \(selectedIndex)")
    }
}

@IBAction func tappedRadioButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.selectedIndex = sender.tag
}
```

[image: clicked shooter and strategy]

Comment: Please, never ever use tags. They are always the wrong solution to fix a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added selectedIndex in the cell itself, so every cell is creating own object with initial value 0,
this is wrong you need to add this property to the viewController itself and change it through delegate or closure

```
//add this closure to your cell
var didTapRadioButton: (() -> Void)?

//call this closure in the @IBAction for the radio button
@IBAction....{
    didTapRadioButton?()
}

//from ViewController cellforRow(at IndexPath..
cell.didTapRadioButton = { 
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I think I should use delegate as you said thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should store the `selectedIndex` variable in your view controller rather than in your cell.